# If f has no local extrema, then it is monotonic

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, alternative-proof, monotone-functions

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ continuous without local extremas. Show that $f$ is monotonic.

Here is my attempt, proving the contraposition :

If $f$ is not monotonic then $\exists a < b < c \text{ such that }  f(a) < f(b) \text{ and } f(b) > f(c)$ (or reverse sense).

Then I do not know what is the next right thing to say : maybe "since $f$ is continuous it admits a local extrema."

What do you think is the right thing to say to finish this proof ? Or maybe there is a direct proof you can give me ?

Comment: What do you know about $f([a,c])$?

Comment: ([,]) = (m,M) m is a min and M is a max

Comment: That's not quite correct, but that may just be a typographical problem. It ought to be $[m,M]$, a closed interval. So, what then do you know about $M$ (resp. $m$)?

Comment: Yes I apologize I made a mistake, it was supposed to be [,]. We know that $\forall x \in [a,c], f(x) \leq M$ and $\forall x \in [a,c], f(x) \geq m$

Comment: You should know a bit more. Can the inequality be strict?

Comment: and that $M \neq a, m \neq b$ or  $M \neq b, m \neq a$

Comment: No I cannot, M and m are reached

Comment: Good. What do you know about the point(s) where these values are attained?

Comment: In the case ()<() and ()>(), then I know that M cannot attained at a or c. Then M is reached in ]a,c[, then M is a local extrema. Is it right ?

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less a direct application of the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) :

First notice that constant functions have local extrema everywhere, so $f$ cannot be constant, nor locally constant for that matter.

Now suppose there exists $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$, since $f$ is not locally constant, there also exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(a)\neq f(c)$.

By the extreme value theorem for $f$ continuous on interval $[a,b]$, $f$ reaches a min and  a max on $[a,b]$, but since $f(c)$ is distinct from $f(a),f(b)$ then these cannot be both $a$ and $b$, so either a min or a max exists on an interior point of $(a,b)$.

This contradicts the hypothesis that $f$ has no local extremum, therefore $f$ must be injective (i.e. refutation of $\exists\  f(a)=f(b)$).

We conclude invoking the equivalence between strictly monotonic functions and continuous injective functions.